# can update database (ms. access) after input the voting checkbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

**This is the code of login system**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module koneksi
    Public conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\pemilu.accdb")
    Public da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public ds As DataSet
    Public cmd As OleDbCommand
    Public rd As OleDbDataReader
    Public dgv As New DataGridView
End Module
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PasswordTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
        NimTextBox.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnpilih_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnpilih.Click
        conn.Close()
        conn.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM pemilih WHERE nim = '" &
                           NimTextBox.Text & "' AND password = '" &
                           PasswordTextBox.Text & "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim userfound As Boolean = False
        Dim firstname As String = ""
        Dim lastname As String = ""

        While rd.Read
            If NimTextBox.Text = rd("nim").ToString And PasswordTextBox.Text = rd("password").ToString Then
                userfound = True
                firstname = rd("firstname").ToString
                lastname = rd("lastname").ToString
            End If
        End While

        If userfound = True Then
            MsgBox("Pilihlah Pemimpin Sesuai Hati Nurani Anda. Selamat Memilih.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Selamat Memilih")
            NimTextBox.Text = ""
            PasswordTextBox.Text = ""
            Form1.Label1.Text = "Selamat Memilih, " & firstname & " " & lastname
            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Maaf, NIM Atau Password Anda Masukkan Salah Atau NIM Anda Belum Terdaftar. Silahkan Ulangi Kembali.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
            NimTextBox.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PasswordTextBox_Keypress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles PasswordTextBox.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
            btnpilih_Click(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            PasswordTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = False
        Else
            PasswordTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[This is the database of login system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj9hS.png)

[This is the login form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjyIu.png)

it works at its best.

---

**This is the code of voting**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnpilih_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnpilih.Click
        conn.Close()
        conn.Open()

        If ckagus.Checked And cksuyamto.Checked And ckfarid.Checked Then
            MsgBox("Anda hanya bisa memilih satu kandidat", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
        ElseIf ckagus.Checked And cksuyamto.Checked Then
            MsgBox("Anda hanya bisa memilih satu kandidat", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
        ElseIf ckagus.Checked And ckfarid.Checked Then
            MsgBox("Anda hanya bisa memilih satu kandidat", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
        ElseIf cksuyamto.Checked And ckfarid.Checked Then
            MsgBox("Anda hanya bisa memilih satu kandidat", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
        ElseIf ckagus.Checked Then
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE kandidat SET [agus] = agus + 1", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Terimakasih karena sudah memilih", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
            Form2.NimTextBox.Focus()
        ElseIf cksuyamto.Checked Then
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE kandidat SET [suyamto] = suyamto + 1", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Terimakasih karena sudah memilih", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
            Form2.NimTextBox.Focus()
        ElseIf ckfarid.Checked Then
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE kandidat SET [farid] = farid + 1", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Terimakasih karena sudah memilih", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info")
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
            Form2.NimTextBox.Focus()
        End If
        ckagus.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        cksuyamto.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        ckfarid.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Label1.Text = "Selamat Memilih, Admin " Then
            btnreport.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[This is the database to count the point of candidate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7WQu.png)

[This is the form of voting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRniQ.png)

The problem is :

1. Base on the voting code, i can't sum the value field on kandidat table when i choose on of candidate.
2. is my code wrong? but, there is no error when i run the program, and the value of kandidat table never increase.
   ???

Comment: It may be difficult to get forum help with this much code.  I recommend you create a tiny project *with only what is needed* to test and prove your issue.  This is often a good troubleshooting technique and will also get you assistance much faster.

Comment: @GlennHolden should i make a video?

Comment: Only if it is necessary to communicate what is happening.  In this case I think a video overkill and would only show that nothing is happening.  It is a very good exercise for you to isolate the issue.  99% of the time I solve my own issue doing this.